# Dynamically change height of UIView to fit content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, xcode7

I'm new to Swift (coming over from PHP).  I'm a little lost as the behaviour of `UIView` seems to be a little inconsistent for me.

On my main screen I have an activity list, with each activity item contained in a UIView.  This interface is built on a UITableView with a custom prototype cell.

Tapping on an item causes a segue into a new view that should display the full article.  What I'm noticing however is that while my UIView's within the table cells seem to auto adjust their height to fit the length of the text content.  The UIView I'm using for my article background does not resize.

I've not set a fixed height for the UIView (although Xcode7 seems to want me to).  I've also confirmed that my label is in fact wrapping the text correctly, the UIView just simply doesn't grow and so it truncates the article.

My rough layout is:

**Working**: UITableViewController -> CustomTableCell -> UIView -> Detail items

**Not working**: UIViewController -> UIView -> Detail items

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm building this in storyboard mode.

I'm including a screenshot of the layouts.  The one on the left works perfectly, the one on the right however the UIView (white area) does not stretch veritcally.[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing your tableview delegate methods? Especially the CellForRowAtIndexPath and HeightForRowAtIndexPath methods?

Comment: NSNoob, I don't mind but as I mentioned it works perfectly in the tableview.

Comment: The issue is in a UIViewController I'm trying to use UIView in again.  My confusion is that it seems to work just fine in the TableView but when I insert a UIView into a (completely separate) UIControllerView, the height doesn't seem to autofit the content

Comment: So basically you have a tableview of certain activities. The view of the cell contains the info you are displaying. On tapping, you want to segue to another VC which then shows the complete article. How are you using The view which you have dedicated to showing detailed article in the tableview? You inserted it as a subview in the cell? And later you insert it as a subview in the destination Vc on cell selection?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm extremely new to IOS as a whole.  :)  So basically I have a UITableViewController ... this lists all the cells for the info I'm display.  Tapping one of the cells segues (show) to a UIViewController and passes the relevant data to the new view.  I'm not doing any subviews.

Comment: I am confused though. That specific UIView, how do you use it in the tableview? As you are saying it is working correctly in the tableview. Are you sure that view is being used in the tableview at all? That's why I wanted to see the delegate methods. TableViewCells come with their own uiview. Segue delegate method in the fromVC and viewDidLoad of the toVC might also be helpful in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, I edited the post and added a screenshot of the layout.  So the UIView on the left works perfectly.  The UIView on the right however does not.

Does this make more sense now?

Comment: The TableView's hierarchy is:

`Tableview -> Prototype Cell -> Content View -> View Container (UIView) -> Individual items`

The UIViewController is
`View -> View Container -> Individual items`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91162/discussion-between-sean-and-nsnoob).

Comment: The one on the left is included in the cell's view so obviously it works fine. A few more questions and we might get somewhere. On the right VC, how are you adding the UI in question? On basis of what I guess I'd say It will not stretch "automatically". You have to use the correct bounds and the ui controls. I would suggest using UITextView to display the full article. No matter how long it is, just provide it the text it needs in the segue delegate. If you need to show company info etc, pass it the same way and display it on top. Where it ends, place the uitextview.

Comment: override intrinsicContentSize for the custom view and calculate the height of the contents. this is what UILabel does to size itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UITextView` to display the full article below your custom view. The `UIView` is not supposed to resize automatically to accomodate full article in the destination VC.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  You are absolutely correct, and I like having the stationary headings and just having the article body scroll. ;)